# Static and non static function class togheter

Tags: php

Can someone explain me and make some example for a static and non static class that works together?

like:

```
App::MySQL()->insert();

App::User()->name;
```

i can't find anything on web.

Thanks

Comment: Try doing a search for ["registry design pattern"](https://www.google.com/#q=registry+design+pattern).

Comment: the `insert()` function doesn't have to be non-static. It still works if `insert` function defined as `static`

Answer (score 0):

The first part (e.g. App::MySQL(), App::User()) is calling a static method on a class in order to return a singleton instance (meaning if an instance of that class exists return it, else create a new one and return it), this makes sure that you have at most one instance of that class. Then you call its methods or get its properties (the second part: ->insert(), ->name)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class App {

    public static function MySQL() {
        return new MySQL();
    }
}

class MySQL {

    public function insert() {
        echo "inserting some stuff\n";
    }

}


App::MySQL()->insert();
```

gives

```
ivo@atmycomputer ~$ php test.php 
inserting some stuff
ivo@atmycomputer ~$
```